# I need help in a select statement Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my Table Called Accounts

```
Code         name
-----------  ----------
301          Data1
301001       Data1.1
109          Data2
109001       Data2.1
311          Data3
311001       Data3.1
```

I want to select all data + 2 Columns to be like This where the other 2 columns the first one will be the first 3 number in the code and second will be the name of the substring

```
Code   |   name    |    code2  |    name2
----------------------------------------
301    |   Data1   |    301    |    Data1
301001 |   Data1.2 |    301    |    Data1
109    |   Data2   |    109    |    Data2  
109001 |   Data2.1 |    109    |    Data2
311    |   Data3   |    311    |    Data3
311001 |   Data3.1 |    311    |    Data3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it looks like the table structure is not very well designed. It is good idea to have a ParentId column with a link to parent account (Columns: Id | Code | Name | ParentId)

In this case the query will be very simple:

```
SELECT N.Code, N.Name, M.Code AS Code2, M.Name AS Name2
FROM Accounts AS N
INNER JOIN Accounts AS M ON N.ParentId = M.Id OR N.ParentId IS NULL
```

---

But, if you have no control on the database structure and you have what you have - I can propose a hacky solution:

```
SELECT N.Code, N.Name, M.Code AS Code2, M.Name AS Name2
FROM Accounts AS N
INNER JOIN Accounts AS M 
  ON N.Code LIKE (M.Code + '%') AND CHARINDEX('.', M.Name) = 0
```

See SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/474e2/7

Query assumes that parent accounts does not have dots in their name!

---

Another query can be built based on assumption that master account code is always shorter than child account:

```
SELECT N.Code, N.Name, M.Code AS Code2, M.Name AS Name2
FROM Accounts AS N
INNER JOIN Accounts AS M 
  ON N.Code LIKE (M.Code + '%') AND LEN(N.Code) >= LEN(M.Code)
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/474e2/9

Comment: this is helped me but it return some redundant data